# $H^n(S,A)$ as a $G/S$ module given $S\lhd G$: non-unique $G/S$ actions?

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences

My question is about a lemma in Joseph J. Rotman's textbook, An Introduction to Homologyical Algebra (2nd Edition).

Let $G$ be a group and let $A$ be a $G$-module. In his Lemma 9.82(ii) on P567, he states that

> If $S$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $H^n(S,A)$ is a $G/S$-module. Moreover, if $A$ is a trivial $G$-module, then $H^n(S,A)$ is a trivial $G/S$-module.

I understand Rotman's construction (see P564-568) that makes $H^n(S,A)$ into a $G/S$-module, and indeed, according to his construction, if $A$ is a trivial $G$-module then $H^n(S,A)^{G/S} = H^n(S,A)$, i.e. $H^n(S,A)$ is a trivial $G/S$-module. However, if we alternatively define the action of $g \in G$ on $H^n(S,A)$ as

$$(g(f))(g_1,g_2,...,g_n) = g.f(g^{-1}g_1g,g^{-1}g_2g,...,g^{-1}g_ng)$$

for any cocycle $f\colon G\times G\times\cdots \times G \rightarrow A$ (really, $f$ is a representative cochain), where $g.a$ denotes the action of $g\in G$ on $a\in A$, as is defined in Ehud Meir's answer in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212636/the-term-h1n-ag-n-in-the-inflation-restriction-exact-sequence, this seem to imply that $H^n(S,A)$ can be a nontrivial $G/S$-module even in the case of $A$ being a trivial $G$-module.

To me, this seems to imply that the $G/S$-action on $H^n(S,A)$ is not uniquely defined. If this is true, then these two $G/S$-actions would lead to to different transgression maps and hence different Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequences; these of course should not alter the cohomology of the total group $H^n(G,A)$.

To summarize my question: given a group $G$, a $G$-module $A$, and a normal subgroup $S\lhd G$. Is it true that the $G/S$-action on $H^n(S,A)$ is not uniquely defined?

Comment: I would rephrase your question as "is it true that there are two natural $G/S$-actions?". The way it is phrased now sounds like you ask whether there exists a unique action, which is probably not what you have in mind (there are of course in general probably infinitely many completely random and irrelevant actions of $G/S$ on $H^n(S,A)$).

Comment: @CaptainLama The way I phrased my question was indeed misleading. What I really wanted to ask is "what is the $G/S$ action used in the LHS spectral sequence?" I think know I have the answer.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks for helping phrase the question. Indeed, what I really want to ask is "what is the $G/S$ action used in the LHS spectral sequence?" Then two choices exist: the first is the one defined in Rotman's book, and the second is the one I wrote as a single-line formula in the OP. Checking the original paper by Hochschild and Serre, I found that it is the second choice that they used.

Comment: The Hochschild & Serre paper explicitly mentioned these two choices of making $H^n(S,A)$ into a $G/S$ module. The LHS spectral sequence will be different depending on the choices. In this sense, I would say the spectral sequence is not uniquely defined.

Comment: Please let me know if I have expressed myself in a clear way. If so, I will modify the original post to refect these thoughts.

Comment: Your use of "uniquely defined" is at best confusing (possibly a language issue?). To say that something is not uniquely defined more or less amounts to saying we cannot refer to it with the article "the". But we can definitely talk about *the* Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence, it's perfectly well-defined. What you may want to say is that there are other spectral sequences involving the same terms.